# Ubuntu 20.04 Cloning

Tags: 20.04, clone

I have a server with 2x EPYC 7402's with Ubuntu 20.04 set up exactly the way I need to run some processing code. I recently got a new sever with 2x EPYC 7F72's. I matched the bios settings as best I could (they have different motherboards so the bios are slightly different). I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and installed everything but the processing code takes twice as long to run. This doesn't make sense considering the 7F72 has the same number of cores and runs faster than the 7402. To rule out it being an install error I'd like to clone the installation of the 7402 server on to the 7F72 server. Firstly, is this possible? Second, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: "7402"? The Integrated circuit? "7F72"?? In general, "cloning" only "works" with the same hardware. There are hardware-specific decisions made **at install time** that simply copying, even if you use a cloning tool, is suboptimal.

Comment: _"but the processing code takes twice as long to run."_ ← This is your problem. Without proper/correct _diagnosis_ you are proceeding to a _treatment_, which most likely will not solve your problem.

Comment: Agreed that it's my problem, but I'm trying to diagnose and rule out possible causes by making sure it is the exact same OS/package installation.